# Sort a numpy array according to 2nd column only if values in 1st column are same

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, opencv, numpy

I have a numpy array which contains coordinates got by using `findNonZero()` method of OpenCV. I want to sort them in order to draw contours.

**Example unsorted numpy array (not coordinates):**

```
 [[ 0, 2],
  [ 0, 0],
  [-1, 8],
  [-6, 7],
  [-1, 1]]
```

**Expected sorted numpy array:**

```
 [[-6, 7],
  [-1, 1],
  [-1, 8],
  [ 0, 0],
  [ 0, 2]]
```

**I want the array to be sorted according to the first column and if values in the first column are equal, i want it to be sorted according to the second column.** Is there a way to do so with least time complexity since the processing is to be done on cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) -

```
a[np.lexsort(a[:,::-1].T)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: a
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 0,  0],
       [-1,  8],
       [-6,  7],
       [-1,  1]])

In [43]: a[np.lexsort(a[:,::-1].T)]
Out[43]: 
array([[-6,  7],
       [-1,  1],
       [-1,  8],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  2]])
```

Comment: Awesome! worked like a charm! Thanks :D Also could you please tell me what `T` is or means? 
PS. Could you suggest a method to draw contours for the sorted list? Normal opencv method `drawContours()` output is all awry.

Comment: @hulkinBrain That's transpose. `np.lexsort` tries to sort each column based on other columns. Since, we are trying to sort rows we need that transpose. We need that flipping because with lexsort, the primary sort order would be the last element and in our case, its the first elem in each row.

Comment: @hulkinBrain For drawing I would suggest, getting the contours as `(Nx2)` shaped arrays for each contour and iteratively assign into the image array that is initialized as a zeros array at the start.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Coordinates are in the example array's format only. Are you suggesting that i draw lines from one coordinate to other in a sequential manner iteratively?

Comment: @hulkinBrain Well I am assuming you are using `findContours`, which would give you list of arrays (I think). So, you could iterate through that list and draw one contour at a time.

Comment: No i'm not mate. I'm identifying white points in an image and then storing them in an array. But i think i might've figured out a way to do that while typing this comment XD Thanks for your help mate! :D