# Filtering coordinate points on the basis of nearest distance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which contains coordinates points like this

```
[[ 581  925]
 [ 582  926]
 [ 582  931]
 [ 582  939]
 [ 584  933]
 [ 584  937]
 [ 585  943]
 [ 586  944]
 [ 589  944]]
```

As you can see there are points which have same x coordinates but different y coordinates. **Starting from the first coordinate, distance to the next closest immediate coordinate is calculated.** 

Like for example, **distance from `[581 925]` to next nearest coordinate is found out. The candidates are `[ 582  926], [ 582  931] & [ 582  939]` since these are the immediate coordinates which are the closest to `[581 925]`.**

As it's obvious in this case that `[582 926]` is the nearest coordinate to `[581 925]`, I only want that coordinate to exist and the other 2 candidate coordinates to be deleted. So the resultant array should be

```
[[ 581  925]
 [ 582  926]
      .
      .
      .
 [ 589  944]]
```

Now same operation should be performed starting from `[582  926]` and so on till the end.

Contour with unfiltered coordinates:
[image]

Contour with filtered coordinates:
[image]

**What is the most pythonic (favorably numpy) approach for this with the least time complexity since it's of the utmost concern?**

NOTE: Line Thinning is not of concern, only concern is of removing the unnecessary points/coordinates.

Comment: Could you please specify which distance metric do you want to use to determine the closest coordinate?

Comment: So, basically you want to compute the distances between nearest coordinates, where by nearest you mean those less distant? Without computing the distances first?

Comment: @Tristan Euclidean, i'll be using `numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)` to calculate the distance

Comment: @NAmorim No, i want to draw contours using these points and want to remove the points which will prevent me from drawing the best contour. I'll add images in the question.

Comment: @NAmorim Since having more than one points with same x-axis value creates a thick and jagged contour, i only want to keep the point which is the nearest to the previous one.

Comment: Do you have any requirement for the quality of the output contour?

Comment: @NAmorim i want to remove the jagged lines. The image which contains the thick line is a combination of jagged lines. In other images where i draw contours, the condition is much worse. If the filtering is done, possibility of jagged lines would be avoided. The quality will be best if the filtering of coordinates mentioned in the question is done.

Comment: As a suggestion, have you consider using image smoothing techniques to do the job? Although it may be easier to go with your brute force solution.

Comment: @NAmorim The coordinates which i have in the array are got after doing dynamic calculations, the coordinates are not obtained by applying findContours() method of openCV. These are custom coordinates so i cant apply smoothing filters here. These set of coordinates are just a part of a bigger coordinate set which will be calculated on the go and appended to this array.

Comment: This (line thinning) can be accomplished using image morphology, see the literature and scipy.ndimage.morphology.

Comment: @Benjamin Please see the updated question. I've updated the images and added a note for better understanding.

Comment: What if the first coordinate has multiple ones, i.e. lets say the first two coords were [581, 924], [581, 925]? So, the question is where should we start from?

Comment: @Divakar That's why i asked the grouping question, one coordinate is picked from the first group and then the calculations are made for the consecutive groups with respect to the previous ones. since [581, 924], [581, 925] would be in the first group, anyone of them can be picked, let's say [581, 924] is picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

For the method to work, **first the array has to be split into sup groups on the basis of equal x-axis values.** Please refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030478/group-2d-numpy-array-elements-which-have-equal-1st-column-values/42030529?) for detailed information. I'll be adding the code below though. *It's important that the array is sorted in ascending order with respect to x-axis.* If it's not, you can do so by applying `np.lextsort` on the array. Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284421/sort-a-numpy-array-according-to-2nd-column-only-if-values-in-1st-column-are-same) to understand how to apply lexsort correctly. A huge thanks to **[@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar)** for providing awesome answers to these posts.

**Code:**

```
# Initial array of coordinates

a = np.array([[ 581  925]
     [ 582  926]
     [ 582  931]
     [ 582  939]
     [ 584  933]
     [ 584  937]
     [ 585  943]
     [ 586  944]
     [ 589  944]])

# Following line splits the array into subgroups on the basis of equal x-axis elements
a = np.split(a, np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)[1][1:], axis=0)

# Array after splitting
# [array([[581, 925]]), 
#  array([[582, 926], [582, 931], [582, 939]]), 
#  array([[584, 933], [584, 937]]), 
#  array([[585, 943]]), 
#  array([[586, 944]]), 
#  array([[589, 944]])]

i = 0

# filteredList will initially contain the first element of the array's first sub group
filteredList = np.reshape(np.asarray(a[0][0]), (-1, 2)) # filteredList = [[581 925]]

while not i == len(a) - 1:
    if len(a[i + 1]) > 1:
        # Following line calculates the euclidean distance between current point and the points in the next group
        min_dist_point_addr = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(filteredList[i] - a[i + 1], axis=1))

        # Next group is reassigned with the element to whom the distance is the least
        a[i + 1] = a[i + 1][min_dist_point_addr]

    # The element is concatenated to filteredList
    filteredList = np.concatenate((filteredList, np.reshape((a[i+1]), (1, 2))), axis=0)
    i += 1

print filteredList
```

**Output:**

```
[[581 925]
 [582 926]
 [584 933]
 [585 943]
 [586 944]
 [589 944]]
```

Comment: Good to see you finally getting through with it!

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! You too helped a lot!