# Group 2D numpy array elements which have equal 1st column values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array like this

```
[[ 569  897]
 [ 570  898]
 [ 570  900]
 [ 571  901]
 [ 571  905]
 [ 572  906]]
```

I want the **elements which have equal values in the first column to be grouped** together in the following way.

```
[[  569  897]
 [[ 570  898]
  [ 570  900]]
 [[ 571  901]
  [ 571  905]]
 [  572  906] ]
```

How should i do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.unique` to get the *separating* indices and then use `np.split` to actually split -

```
np.split(a, np.unique(a[:,0], return_index=1)[1][1:],axis=0)
```

Alternatively, with slicing and using `np.flatnonzero` -

```
np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(a[1:,0] != a[:-1,0])+1,axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [63]: a
Out[63]: 
array([[569, 897],
       [570, 898],
       [570, 900],
       [571, 901],
       [571, 905],
       [572, 906]])

In [64]: out = np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(a[1:,0] != a[:-1,0])+1,axis=0)

In [65]: out[0]
Out[65]: array([[569, 897]])

In [66]: out[1]
Out[66]: 
array([[570, 898],
       [570, 900]])

In [67]: out[2]
Out[67]: 
array([[571, 901],
       [571, 905]])

In [68]: out[3]
Out[68]: array([[572, 906]])
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for your proposed method? It isn't working as i want it to.

Comment: @hulkinBrain Well I assumed the first column to be sorted, am I correct to assume that? It should work then, otherwise could you provide such a sample?

Comment: Yeah first column is sorted.

Comment: @hulkinBrain Added one.

Comment: Yes, it did produce the output. I made a silly mistake, my bad. Thanks! Can you help me out with another problem of mine? This one has been bugging me for many hours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027261/filtering-coordinate-points-on-the-basis-of-nearest-distance

Comment: What if the elements are not sorted? What if the elements are like this: `[ 569,  897], [ 570,  898],  [ 570,  900],  [ 571,  901],  [ 571,  905],  [ 572,  906], [ 570,  898],  [ 570,  900]`

Comment: @hulkinBrain Lexsort it : `a[np.lexsort(a.T)]`.