# Poor performance when looping over numpy array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, performance, point-clouds

With the function get_height I calculate the height difference between two point clouds for every scan (y,z-coordinates in my example).

My algorithm works but takes 1.93 s on average. How can I improve the performance?

EDIT: I attached a fully working example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_random_dataset(N,x_max):
    # Create the 'x' column
    unique_x = np.linspace(0, x_max, x_max*10+1)
    x = np.random.choice(unique_x, N) # Generate the array with repeated values

    # Create the 'y' column
    y = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, N)

    # Create the 'z' column
    z = - y**2 + 5 + np.random.normal(0, 1, N)

    # Create the 'A' array
    A = np.column_stack((x, y, z))

    return A

def get_height(A0,A1):
    # get unique x values that are in both scans
    ux0 = np.unique(A0[:,0])
    ux1 = np.unique(A1[:,0])
    ux = np.intersect1d(ux0,ux1)

    # get height at each unique x value
    h = []
    for x in ux:
        # get slice of lower scan
        mask0 = (A0[:,0] == x)
        z0 = A0[mask0,2]
        
        # get slice of upper scan
        mask1 = (A1[:,0] == x)
        z1 = A1[mask1,2]

        # get height difference
        height = np.max(z1) - np.max(z0)

        # append results to list
        h.append(height)

    # convert list to array
    h = np.array(h)

    return ux, h

# run script
A0 = generate_random_dataset(N=300000,x_max=100)
A1 = generate_random_dataset(N=310000,x_max=120)
A1[:,2] = A1[:,2] - 0.001*(A1[:,0]-50)**2 + 5 # make A1 higher and different than A0


# apply function
%timeit ux,h = get_height(A0,A1)
ux0 = np.unique(A0[:,0])
ux1 = np.unique(A1[:,0])
ux = np.intersect1d(ux0,ux1)

# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.24*1.5,3*1.5))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.scatter(ux,h)
ax.set_xlabel('x [mm]')
ax.set_ylabel('h [mm]')
plt.show()
```

I've tried using np.lexsort approach from a previous question of mine but that approach doesn't work for two arrays.

I want to approach this problem differently (without looping over unique x values) but I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: this may help [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array)

Comment: consider making [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will be easier to help you -> more people will be willing to help you

Comment: a fully running code makes it easier to help

Comment: I've attached a working example. Thank you for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a `numpy` solution, but in the meantime using `pandas` is much faster than a `python` loop with lookup in each iteration, even including the overhead of converting the arrays into dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_height_pd(A0, A1):
    df0 = pd.DataFrame(A0)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(A1)
    m0 = df0.groupby(0)[2].max()
    m1 = df1.groupby(0)[2].max()
    return (m1 - m0).dropna()  # dropna gets rid of the non-intersecting ones
```

Alternatively, possibly a little faster, use series.

```
def get_height_s(A0, A1):
    s0 = pd.Series(A0[:, 2])
    s1 = pd.Series(A1[:, 2])
    m0 = s0.groupby(A0[:, 0]).max()
    m1 = s1.groupby(A1[:, 0]).max()
    return (m1 - m0).dropna()
```

Comment: DataFrame solution: 21.7 ms
Series solution: 19.5 ms

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly `numpy` solution using [this function to get the min and max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58908648/567595). Transpose one of the arrays so that it is all below and in opposite direction to the other (`y' = offset - y` where offset is a suitable low number), concatenate the two arrays together, then find the min and max for each x. The min in each row will be `offset - maximum` from A1, and the max in each row will be the maximum from A0. Then reverse the transposition to get the difference in heights.

```
def agg_minmax(a):  # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58908648/567595
    sidx = np.lexsort(a[:,::-1].T)
    b = a[sidx]
    m = np.r_[True,b[:-1,0]!=b[1:,0],True]
    return np.c_[b[m[:-1],:2], b[m[1:],1]]

def get_height(A0, A1):
    min0 = A0[:, 2].min()
    offset = min0 + A1[:, 2].min() - 1
    b0 = A0[:, [0, 2]]
    b1 = np.array([A1[:, 0], offset - A1[:, 2]]).T
    c = np.concatenate((b0, b1))
    agg = agg_minmax(c)
    f = agg[(agg[:, 1] < min0) & (agg[:, 2] >= min0)]   # filter out the not-applicable rows
    return f[:, 0], offset - f[:, 1] - f[:, 2]
```

It's slower than the pandas solutions but perhaps can be tweaked.

Comment: Using the provided example i got 182 ms ± 10.1 ms per loop.