# how to eliminate very close points in an area to filter the interest points?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, data-mining

Im working on interest points and Im searching for a way to filter the very close points to avoid redundancy and facilitate the description, someone has an idea? thnx

Comment: Have a look at adaptive non-maxima supression (you can find it in this free book http://szeliski.org/Book/).

Comment: i'll see it thank you :)

Comment: Hi, check this [fitering points on the basis of nearest distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027261/filtering-coordinate-points-on-the-basis-of-nearest-distance) thread.

Comment: thnx a lot :)...